# How to split a column into two columns by first and last found pattern in Pandas (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, split

i have a problem with splitting a column into two columns. I want to split the column by the first and last found pattern '-'. Maybe this is trivial.

Here is my column:

```
        col1
0       aa-bb-cc-dd
1       aa-bb-cc
2       aa-bb-cc
3       aa-bb-cc-dd
```

This is the frame i want as result:

```
        col1           col2
0       bb-cc          dd
1       bb             cc
2       bb             cc
3       bb-cc          dd
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([i.split('-', 1)[1].rsplit('-', 1) for i in df['col1']],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2'])

print(df)

    col1 col2
0  bb-cc   dd
1     bb   cc
2     bb   cc
3  bb-cc   dd
```

Pandas `str` methods exist primarily for convenience. For clean data, you may find the list comprehension more efficient for larger dataframes.

Comment: This solution takes 1.1 seconds for 700k rows--the fastest I've tested so far!  3x faster than using Series.str.split().

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idiomatic but slow way to do it:

```
df.col1 = df.col1.str.split('-', 1).str[1] # discard first part
parts = df.col1.str.rsplit('-', 1).str
df.col1 = parts[0]
df['col2'] = parts[1]
```

While this works, it is not fast: about 4 seconds for 700k rows.  Looking at it you'd think this is a good way to do it, but performance-wise it's worse than all the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your question, you need to get rid of the first block delimited by a '-', then split the last '-' block in col2. If that is what you need, you could consider this:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'col1':['aa-bb-cc-dd', 'aa-bb-cc', 'aa-bb-cc', 'aa-bb-cc-dd']})
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x[x.rfind('-')+1:])
df['col1'] =  df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x[x.find('-')+1:x.rfind('-')])
print (df)
```

Comment: `apply()` is usually quite slow.  If we want to iterate we can just write for loops.

Comment: This solution takes 1.8 seconds for 700k rows.

Answer (score 1):

First slice and use [`str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) and [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
df = df.col1.str[3:].str.rsplit('-', n=1, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'col1',1:'col2'})

print(df)
    col1 col2
0  bb-cc   dd
1     bb   cc
2     bb   cc
3  bb-cc   dd
```

Comment: `dict(zip([0,1],['col1','col2']))` is just `{0: 'col1', 1: 'col2'}`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I thought to create dict dynamically but here only 2 columns not needed and thank you.

Comment: If you needed to do it dynamically, `zip([0,1],['col1','col2'])` is better written as `enumerate(['col1', 'col2'])`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck It's good, I thought to use `range` but I will use `enumerate` trick from now.

Comment: This solution takes 3.9 seconds for 700k rows.

Comment: Given the data is clean, better to use list comprehension for performance. If it's not containing null or some noise better to use pandas str functions.

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].split('-')[-1]
df['col1'] = '-'.join(i for i in df['col1'].split('-')[1:-1])
```

Comment: You're missing some `str`s in there.